# How to install open-vm-toolbox on Kali Linux?

Tags: vmware

I try to install `open-vm-toolbox` on my virtual machine.
I tried `apt-get update`and `apt-get install open-vm-toolbox`afterwards, but i get: 'Package open-vm-toolbox not found'

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Kali versions**

Type the following command:

```
   apt-get update
   apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse
   reboot
```

If this install is failed , you need to istall `linux-headers`.

```
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

**Old Kali versions:**

install vmware-tool patche

```
cd ~
apt-get install git gcc make linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git
cd vmware-tools-patches
```

Mount the VMware tools ISO by clicking “Install VMware Tools”

copy the installer to the downloads directory and then run the installer script :

Example:

```
   cd ~/vmware-tools-patches
   cp /media/cdrom/VMwareTools-9.9.0-2304977.tar.gz downloads/
 ./untar-and-patch-and-compile.sh
```

Change `VMwareTools-9.9.0-2304977.tar.gz` with your current version

Comment: Thank you. I tried it without `apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. It works without it too, why do i need it?